# Entity Framework/WPF - Is it sensible to bind directly to DbSet<T>.Local?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I'm currently binding my WPF view directly to the 'Local' (Observable) collection of my DbSet object. ('Models' is the name of the collection in this example)

```
this.Models = this.context.Models.Local;       
this.context.Models.Load();
this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Models);
this.Models.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(ModelsChanged);
```

This seemed incredibly convenient, not having to move models between collections on load. The problem I'm having is the collection seemingly cannot be ordered in anyway. Not without reloading from the DB anyway. Is there a way to sort this collection or is this not what the Local collection is intended for?

Comment: try a CollectionViewSource http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/387#.U0PBXPldV8E ... http://blog.nicktown.info/2008/12/10/using-a-collectionviewsource-to-display-a-sorted-entitycollection.aspx

Comment: @ColinSmith both those links are dead - go to spammy parked pages. boo hiss internet.

Comment: @CAD I know :(...which is why it's handy to run something like httrack yourself periodically ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I can sort/filter the Local collection as follows;

```
ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(this.Models);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Column", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```